# Append to PostgreSQL database with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, psycopg2

I have a Pandas dataframe with all of the required columns for a PostgreSQL database, and I'm trying to add the rows of the dataframe into the database and allow it to generate the optional columns on its own by calling `df.to_sql(TABLE_NAME, ENGINE, if_exists='append', index=False)`, but it's giving me the following error:

```
ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.InsufficientPrivilege) permission denied for schema public
LINE 2: CREATE TABLE "table_name" (
```

I'm guessing this error is happening since it's trying to create the table when it already exists (albeit with different column types, such as TEXT instead of VARCHAR). I tried to insert a single row into the table using `cursor.execute` with psycopg2 and it worked fine. Do I need to add something to the `to_sql` function or is it just not possible to add a dataframe to a PostgreSQL database without all the columns present?

I'm creating the engine using `ENGINE = create_engine(f'postgresql+psycopg2://{USER}:{PASSWORD}@{HOST}/{DATABASE}')`.

Comment: TEXT vs VARCHAR doesn't matter, but of course all the columns have to exist.  pandas isn't going to modify the table.

Comment: `permission denied` tells you that you don't have the permissions to do so. It doesn't matter if the table exists or not, this error comes even before checking the existence of a table.

Comment: @FrankHeikens That's weird because I use the exact same username and password as I do for psycopg2 connection cursor.execute and it works fine without the permission error. If I don't have permission to modify the table I'd imagine I'd get permission denied with psycopg2 connection cursor as well.

Comment: 1) You should be doing [Creating URLs Programmatically](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/engines.html#creating-urls-programmatically). Not that I think that this is the cause of your issue, just that it will do proper escaping. 2) Best guess is you are not connecting to the database you think you are in the Pandas case. 3) The permission error is not on the table it is; *... permission denied for schema public*. 4) I betting you are working with Postgres 15 in the Pandas case. FYI, always include software version info in your question.

Comment: There must be a difference between the two connections, a different user or maybe even a different database or server. There is no way that you just for this connection with the same user and database don’t have the permission while using a different connection everything works fine

Comment: I think the problem was that Pandas's to_sql function is attempting to create a new table (which I don't have permission to do) since I'm guessing I don't have all the columns of the table in the dataframe. I'm able to get around this problem by directly inserting rows into the existing table with cursor.execute.

Comment: Or more likely because you not using the correct table name. Check the capitalization of the name in the database and then check the Postgres logs for how the table name is coming from Pandas.